# Stack two images and merge them into a single one in javascript

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation

I've made some research on this but haven't found any solution, so I'm not sure it is even possible, but here is my problem:

I'm developing a website using only HTML/CSS + Javascript, using a REST API, and I need to merge two images in one to use it as an icon for the google maps API. I can't do it on the server because it depends on the client, and I need to provide an image at the end.
I've seen some things, like [pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blend/), but it isn't supported in IE and unfortunately some people still use that :p...

Do you know other ways to do that?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: actually, you just have to use Google's overlay tools in the API. I just put one Marker on top of the other and adjusted the size and position using the MarkerImage class.

Comment: Do you support IE8-? If not, using canvas would be a great solution I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put one over the other and change the opacity of the top one: http://jsfiddle.net/cAWJs/

Using blend modes like your example site you would need canvas support though.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work, since the google maps API seems really to want a single image as a cursor, but I'll try anyway

Comment: What about the API's overlay tool?

Comment: Actually, it was just that! Just have to put two markers one on top of the others, and adjust with the MarkerImage class. Thanks!